# Send image to api rest with httpie or other

Tags: django, api, http, request, django-rest-framework

I have the following model:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="originals", blank=True)
    entity = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ENTITIES,
                              default=ENTITY_CLASIFICADO)
```

The following serializer:

```
class PictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ("pk", "image", "entity")
```

And this viewset:

```
class PictureViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Picture.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PictureSerializer
```

I want through httpie and the python requests package to do a POST of an image and an entity.

The image I want to send to the API is on my computer.

The url to make the post is /v1/pictures/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I am using curl for API testing.

To send images from testing i am using below method. May be this will be helpful for you.

$ curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/events/upload **-F 'image=@Image_Path' -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"**

e.g.:

$ curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/events/upload -F 'image=@**/home/shailesh/Pictures/my_image.jpg**' -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"